# Insert values in mysql from android

Tags: android, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am developing an android app in which user will insert values in mysql from android. everything is ok. but when user insert value there are blank values inserted in table. here is my php code:

```
<?php
 require "init.php";
 $host = "localhost";
 $user = "githucco_furqan";
 $password = "githuc.com123";
 $db = "githucco_app";

 $sql_query= "insert into sample values('$name','$email','$mobile');";
     if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query))
       {
         echo"<h3>Data insertion successfully</h3>";
       }
    else
       {
        echo"<h3>Data insertion error...</h3>".mysqli_error($con);
       }
  ?>
```

and my java code is:

```
package com.example.muhammadfurqan.fanuc;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class Add_Info extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText name,email,number;
Button add_button;
String p_name,mail,cell_number;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__info);
    name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number);
    add_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_btn);

}
public void saveinfo(View view){
    p_name = name.getText().toString();
    mail = email.getText().toString();
    cell_number = number.getText().toString();
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask();
    backgroundTask.execute(p_name,mail,cell_number);
}
class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String add_info_url;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        add_info_url = "http://app.githuc.com/android_database_connection/add_info.php";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        String name, email, mobile;
        name = arg[0];
        email = arg[1];
        mobile = arg[2];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(add_info_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"LATIN"),8);
            String data_String = URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("mobile","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(mobile,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data_String);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            Log.d("name = ",name);
            Log.d("email = ",email);
            return "Data has been inserted successfuly";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the values for $name, $email and $mobile from the $POST-Array in php. This should work with

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$mobile =  $_POST["name"];
```

Comment: Or can you otherwise print the values for $name, $email and $mobile and see, if they are set?

Comment: And what is the value of $name, $email and $mobile before entering them into the database? And what is the value of the $_POST-array?

Comment: values of $name,$email,$mobile are empity

Comment: and the value of the $_POST-array?

Comment: Thanks for giving response

Answer (score 0):

The issue because you not get the value for each post params. You need receiving the post params from android before you execute the query. You can see example to post on android & receive the post params on WEB API in this [article](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/).